# Delete lines in file over an hour old using timestamps bash

Tags: bash, sed, timestamp

Having a bit of bother trying to get the following to work.

I have a file containing `hostname:timestamp` as below:

```
hostname1:1445072150
hostname2:1445076364
```

I am trying to create a bash script that will query this file (using a cron job) to check if the timestamp is over 1 hour old and if so, remove the line.
Below is what I have so far but it doesn't appear to be removing the line in the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts=/tmp/hosts
current_timestamp=$(date +%s)

while read line; do
    hostname=`echo $line | sed -e 's/:.*//g'`
    timestamp=`echo $line | cut -d ":" -f 2`
    diff=$(($current_timestamp-$timestamp))
    if [ $diff -ge 3600 ]; then
            echo "$hostname - Timestamp over an hour old. Deleting line."
            sed -i '/$hostname/d' $hosts
    fi
done <$hosts
```

I have managed to get the timestamp part working correctly in identifying hosts that are over an hour old but having trouble removing the time from the file.

I suspect it may be due to the while loop keeping the file open but not 100% sure how to work around it. Also tried making a copy of the file and editing that but still nothing.

ALTERNATIVELY: If there is a better way to get this to work and produce the same result, I am open to suggestions :)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: change to `diff=$((current_timestamp-timestamp))` and quote expansion required for sed : `sed -i "/$hostname/d" $hosts`

Comment: Cheers @amdixon. That seems to have done the trick. Much appreciated :)

Comment: no worries, code was almost working already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your script was just this line:

```
sed -i '/$hostname/d' $hosts
```

Variables inside single-quotes are not expanded to their values,
so the command is trying to replace literally "$hostname", instead of its value. If you replace the single-quotes with double-quotes,
the variable will get expanded to its value, which is what you need here:

```
sed -i "/$hostname/d" $hosts
```

There are improvements possible:

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts=/tmp/hosts
current_timestamp=$(date +%s)

while read line; do
    set -- ${line/:/ }
    hostname=$1
    timestamp=$2
    ((diff = current_timestamp - timestamp))
    if ((diff >= 3600)); then
        echo "$hostname - Timestamp over an hour old. Deleting line."
        sed -i "/^$hostname:/d" $hosts
    fi
done <$hosts
```

The improvements:

- More strict pattern in the sed command, to make it more robust and to avoid some potential errors
- Simpler way to extract hostname part and timestamp part without any sub-shells
- Simpler arithmetic operations by enclosing within `((...))`

Comment: amdixon assisted us in finding the issue with the script but thanks for the improvements, especially explaining each of them (Y)

Answer (score 2):

You ask for alternatives — use `awk`:

```
awk -F: -v ts=$(date +%s) '$2 <= ts-3600 { next }' $hosts > $hosts.$$
mv $hosts.$$ $hosts
```

The `ts=$(date +%s)` sets the `awk` variable `ts` to the value from `date`.  The script skips any lines where the value in the second column (after the first colon) is smaller than the threshold.  You could do the subtraction once in a BEGIN block if you wanted to.  Decide whether `<=` or `<` is correct for your purposes.

If you need to know which lines are deleted, you can add

```
printf "Deleting %s - timestamp %d older than %d\n", $1, $2, (ts-3600) >/dev/stderr;
```

before the `next` to print the information on standard error.  If you must write that to standard output, then you need to arrange for retained lines to be written to a file with `print > file` as an alternative action after the filter condition (passing `-v file="$hosts.$$"` as another pair of arguments to `awk`).  The tweaks that can be made are endless.

If the file is of any significant size, it will be quicker to copy the relevant subsection of the file once to a temporary file and then to the final file than to edit the file in place multiple times as in the original code.  If the file is small enough, there isn't a problem.

Comment: This is a good answer because using awk inside a while loop is a bad idea.